# Gzip for Classic ASP Pages

Tags: asp-classic, gzip

I don't have access to IIS Server as I am hosted on a shared hosting. I don't have access to remote IIS manager or the command prompt on server.

Now, my question is, Is it possible to gzip my asp pages? I am hosted on an IIS 7 server.

Answer (score 0):

Any type of file can be compressed including ASP Classic pages. However, HttpCompression is configured on the web server where the server identifies which extensions should be compressed. If `.asp` files have been marked for compression, then it should be the case that the web sever will add the `Content-encoding: gzip` header for you.

Comment: It looks like the .asp files are not set to compress by default, since I can't see the accept-encoding: gzip in the http headers. How can I enable this? I don't have access to the IIS configuration manager.

Comment: @ctroy - You cannot enable it without access to the IIS configuration. If you did have access to it, you need to enable the feature by checking Static/Dynamic Compression in Control Panel, Programs and Features, Turn Windows Features on or off, Internet Information Services, Performance Features. Then, you would need to go into %SystemRoot%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config and configure the extensions and/or mime types that should be compressed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll have to use global.asa file for handling Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute event
Next gzip or whichever you prefer compression is required, that's available through library functions for asp.net, however for classic try yui compressor or best is implement the compression code manually. An example of consuming it is at
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/02/ASPNET-GZip-Encoding-Caveats
Finally, remember to append content-encoding header client may not cross-examine for compression otherwise.